# Redux State count return

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to build out a feature in my React application showing num of comments for a specific post. Since I don't have this information from backend ill try to make a `.length`on the returned state.

However, it seems like I have built out the reducer in a faulty way but I'm not sure whats wrong with it. Right now I'm just receiving undefined.

Built up as following

#### Action

```
    export function getPostComments(id) {
    const request = API.fetchPostComments(id)

    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: COMMENTS_GET_POSTCOMMENTS, payload: data})
        });
    };
}
```

#### Reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type){
        case COMMENTS_GET_POSTCOMMENTS:
      return {...state, ...action.payload}
```

#### Component

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getPostComments(this.props.id);
    }

....

<span>{`comments ${this.props.comments.length}`}</span>

....


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        comments: state.comments,

    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {postPostVote, getPostComments})(PostComponent);
```

#### EDIT

I am retrieving information from the server if I change my reducer to be `return action.payload`I will first receive a comment number of 2 but then this gets wiped replacing it with a 0 since the last post in the list doesn't have any comments. So I'm overwriting here? And that most be wrong aswell

Repo : https://github.com/petterostergren/readable

*Thanks for now!*

Answer (score 0):

```
export function getAllCategories() {
 return (dispatch) => {
    API.fetchAllCategories()
     .then(data => {
        dispatch({type: CATEGORIES_GET_ALL_CATEGORIES, payload: data})
     });
 };
}
```

The call to your API fetchAllCategories is asynchronous, what you were doing before was that you were calling your API but not waiting for it's response. That is why you were getting `undefined` passed in payload.

So what you needed to do was Chain that fetch call with the another promise.

I am using redux-thunk in my app, and this is how I am using it. See the code below.

```
export function loadPayments () {
   return dispatch => PaymentsAPI.getCustomerPaymentMethods()
                  .then((paymentMethods) => { 
                    dispatch({
                      type: actionTypes.LOAD_PAYMENTS_SUCCESS,
                      payments: paymentMethods
                    }) 
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error', error);
                  })
 }
```

For API Calls I am using Fetch & Axios. You can use any you want. Both are good.

To update your reducer, so that it adds the previous value do the following

```
case actionTypes.LOAD_SAVED_CARDS_SUCCESS: {
  return { 
    ...state, 
    payments: [ ...state.payments, ...action.payments],
    totalpayments: state.payments.length + action.payments.length
  };
}
```

What the reducers will do here is that, it will append all your suppose payments methods i,e previous methods + new methods along with the count update as well.

Comment: Im using redux-thunk as of my understating that helps with the async?

Comment: It does, but even in thunk you need to await the response from that API call.

Comment: Kindly have a look at my updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting. But if I `return action.payload` I will first receive a 2( the first post have two comments)  and the second 0. But this action write so that both get 2 and then both end up on 0

Comment: I understand what you're doing here, makes sense. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it going yet.  Would you mind take a look at the repo?